# iOS11 CoreBluetooth state restoration does not work

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, ios11

The problem is pretty simple.

Core bluetooth state restoration does not work in iOS 11, when it does work properly in iOS 10. I wonder if there anything I should change in order to get it working or is it iOS 11 bug?

Did anyone experienced similar issue?

I got to the point when after "triggering" restoration mode by bluetooth device action I get my "willRestoreState" method called if and only if I toggle bt on/off or get back to range with my device almost the same time when "triggering" is done.

Edit 1: iOS 11.1 beta 2 still same story.

Edit 2: Looks like it is fixed on iOS 11.2 beta 3. Probably it has been fixed on iOS 11.2 beta 1 firstly.

Comment: We are having major issues with State Preservation on iOS 11 as well. I have reported some bugs, but so far only one have been solved.

For me State Preservation fail all the time if your peripheral is still connected an you receive a BLE notification or indication. Maybe you can  test and confirm this.

Comment: Yeah, same story. Try toggle bt right after sending notification.